# How do I use regular expressions in a Cucumber table (multiline argument) to diff against table?

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

I am using a scenario table ([multiline step arguments](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments)) to check some data from a screen using cucumber, using the in built .diff! method on the Cucumber AST table.

I would like to check the content matches against regular expressions.

```
Scenario: One
    Then the table appears as:
    | One   | Two   | Three |
    | /\d+/ | /\d+/ | /\d+/ |
```

The actual table could look something like

```
| One | Two | Three |
| 123 | 456 | 789   |
```

which this scenario is translated to "as long as there are some digits, I don't care"

An example step implementation that fails:

```
Then /^the table appears as:$/ do |expected_table|
  actual_table  = [['One','Two', 'Three'],['123', '456', '789']]
  expected_table.diff! actual_table
end
```

Error:

```
Then the table appears as: # features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:230
      | One    | Two    | Three  |
      | /\\d+/ | /\\d+/ | /\\d+/ |
      | 123    | 456    | 789    |
      Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)
```

I have tried using step transforms to transform the cells into regular expressions, but they still aren't identical.

Transform code:

```
 expected_table.raw[0].each do |column|
    expected_table.map_column! column do |cell|
      if cell.respond_to? :start_with?
        if cell.start_with? "/"
          cell.to_regexp
        else
          cell
        end
      else
        cell
      end
    end
  end
```

which provides the eror:

```
Then the table appears as: # features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:228
      | One          | Two          | Three        |
      | (?-mix:\\d+) | (?-mix:\\d+) | (?-mix:\\d+) |
      | 123          | 456          | 789          |
      Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)
```

Any ideas? I am stuck.

Comment: can you post the error that's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regular expressions in a scenario is almost certainly the wrong approach. Cucumber features are intended to be read and understood by business-focussed stakeholders.

How about writing the step at a higher level, such as as:

```
Then the first three columns of the table should contain a digit
```

Comment: Now I think about it, this makes sense. And I can still check the other data using the diff! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it without writing your own implementation of `diff!` method from Ast::Table. Take a look into `cucumber/lib/ast/table.rb`. Internally it uses [diff-lcs](https://github.com/gioele/diff-lcs) library to do an actual comparison which doesn't support regex match.

Comment: Thanks, I already had looked, but was wondering if anyone knew a quick way to change this. I was trying to avoid rewriting the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to write this in a way that provides the cool diff output.  Otherwise, I'd look at writing this such that you simply check the rows.  It won't be as pretty, and it won't get you the diff of the entire table, but it's something.

```
Then /^the table appears as:$/ do |expected_table|
  actual_table  = [['One','Two', 'Three'],['123', '456', '789']]

  expected_table.raw.each_with_index { |row, y|
    row.each_with_index { |cell, x| 
      actual_table[x][y].should == cell
    }
  }  
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. But shouldn't that be a ~= ?